# What did I miss in this booting-iso-from-disk attempt?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, iso

I have downloaded an LTS version of Ubuntu and put the iso on a separate ext4 partition on a laptop that default boots 18.04.2 LTS. I've added the appropriate line to 40_custom in grub.d, and run `update-grub` successfully. I can boot to the iso from the GRUB boot menu.

I've tried to do this on a desktop computer (NUC), using the same exact line from the 40_custom file (but pointing to the 5th partition, which is the proper one, instead of the 8th), also update-grub(-ing) successfully, but I get an error:

```
error: file `/isos/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso' not found.
error: no server is specified.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Here is the line from `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "ISO: Ubuntu 18.04.1 from (hd0,8)" {
    set isofile="/isos/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,8)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Did I miss something? Did I need to prep the iso first? IIRC, all I needed to do was copy the file to the ext4 partition on the laptop, update 40_custom and properly switch to iso at boot time.

Edit to add:
Both of those devices have nve SSDs.

Edit to add exact GRUB entry from non-ISO-booting NUC:

```
menuentry "ISO: Ubuntu 18.04.2 from (hd0,5)" {
    set isofile="/isos/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Comment: Do you have flash drive also plugged in? I find that changes my drive order & I have to manually edit the hd0 to hd1 when booting with flash drive plugged in.  Drive numbering, & path are the two biggest issues I have, and sometimes just manually edit grub as booting to fix or temporarily make it work. I also use toram parameter, so ISO is all in RAM. I also think 18.04 used vmlinuz.efi, old versions did not have .efi and now newer verisons do not. I often have to open ISO and check what grub has inside ISO.

Comment: No, the only external components were a USB mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Edit to add details about SSD

Comment: The menuentry you list still points to the 8th partition, so I'm assuming you posted the old one? Please post the exact one that isn't working. Also, on my working 18.04 iso boot system, it's just `initrd`, not `initrd.lz`   That won't cause the file not found error on the iso though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I added the actual entry to the question and went to verify that the paths were correct ... low and behold, I hadn't created the `isos` folder, so all the paths were wrong! Fixing that, combined with your suggestion of `initrd` instead of `initrd.lz` and I've got the iso booting! Thanks!

Comment: @OrganicMarble How can I check next time to make sure I use the right parameters? (The LinuxMint and ElementaryOS isos all boot properly with `initrd.lz`, but the ubuntu one does not.)

Comment: You can open the .iso with "archive manager" (I just right click the iso and choose archive manager from the context menus), then go to the casper folder and check.  It's good to check - Ubuntu, Clonezilla, and Boot-Repair all are different!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks. If you aggregate your comments into one answer, I'll accept. Good troubleshooting stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file not found` error means there is some problem with the path to the .iso.  Make sure the files are where you expect them to be.

Also, on my working 18.04 iso boot system, it's just `initrd`, not `initrd.lz` (That won't cause the file not found error on the iso though.) Verify this value for a particular .iso by opening it in "Archive Manager".